# Propositional and predicate logic confusion

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I was told to write the following in propositional logic: "The product of two negative numbers if positive" and "every positive real number has exactly two square roots".

I think I know how to do this using predicate logic. The first one should be $\forall x \forall y (x<0 \land y<0)\rightarrow (x*y>0)$ and the second one should be $\forall x \exists y (x>0)\rightarrow (\sqrt{x}=y \land \sqrt{x}=-y)$. Is this correct?

The real problem is I'm told to write this in propositional logic, which I'm not sure how to do since I'm not allowed to use quantifiers? Is this a mistake or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is correct, your second is not. You've written $\sqrt{x} = y \wedge \sqrt{x} = -y$; by the transitivity of equality, this would require $y = -y$, so $y = 0$ and therefore $x = 0$, which is not what you wanted to say. You should translate "$y$ is a square root of $x$" as "$y \cdot y = x$", not "$y = \sqrt{x}$". Also, even with this modification, your sentence only expresses "every positive real number has two square roots", not "every positive real number has *exactly* two square roots". You should try naming the two roots $y$ and $z$ and trying to express (1) $y$ and $z$ are both square roots of $x$; (2) $y$ and $z$ are different numbers; and (3) no number other than $y$ and $z$ is a square root of $x$.

As for the predicate/propositional logic issue: This sounds like either a mistake or a trick question. If the author of the problem really meant this to be propositional logic, it would be a very easy problem - since neither sentence involves any Boolean connectives, they'd just translate as $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

Comment: Ah I see, So is the correction $\forall x \exists y \exists z ((x>0)\Rightarrow (y*y=x)\land (z*z=x)\land (y\neq z))$ satisfactory? Or is it necessary to include a third variable $\neg\exists w (w*w=x \land (w\neq y \land w\neq z))$?

Comment: You need the third variable, in order to get "exactly" two. Otherwise, yes, your new answer is correct.